# Unable to install pika using pip install

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, pika

Getting the following after launching : `pip install pika`
(I have shorted the exception to first line in trace and last line)

```
Collecting Pika
  using cahced pika-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages : pika
Exception:
Traceback 
File" /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pup/basecommand.py line 223 in main status = self.run(options, args)
.
.
.
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/os.py" line 157 in makedirs
mkdir(name ,mode)
OSError [Errno13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika'
```

Also tried with `sudo` before but I got `sudo pip,command not found`.

Comment: how did you install pip?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it's better to use virtualenv and run your application within a python sandbox but if you still want to install on your system packages I guess you should reinstall pip. if you're on ubuntu or debian just run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install python-pip` and then retry pip install pika with sudo: `sudo pip install pika`

Answer (score 3):

By this way, you are trying to install pika under global python installation, turning it available to whole system.

Permitions for global python installation is granted for root, by default. If you want to really install as global, you should use "sudo" or some other way to run as root, by example, "su".

To install using sudo, you can run like:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pika
```

or, using pip:

```
sudo pip install pika
```

By suggestion, If you don't need a global installation of pika, it is really recommended to install it under virtualenv, isolating this installations between each environment. For more information: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Answer (score 1):

`python3 -m pip install pika`
worked for me.